# Adding a suffix to XML data

Tags: php, arrays, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code that displays the quantity of products purchased by a customer :

```
$items[] = array(
    'QUANTITE'          => $item_data['qty'],
```

If the customer purchased 1 product, the XML file generated will display 1.

However, the information needs to be entered into a software that requires us to enter 2 zeros after the quantity, so 1 product would became 100.

How can I add those 2 zeros after the quantity into the code above?

Kind regards!

Comment: `$item_data['qty'] * 100`? `$item_data['qty']."00";`?

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to hear. I posted it as an answer so you can close the post if you want. But that should not have been so hard to find. Try and invest some more time to reseach the next time you have such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on wether your `$item_data['qty']` is a string or an integer, use:

`$item_data['qty'] * 100` - for integers

or

`$item_data['qty']."00"` - for a string value.